# Preserve line breaks when converting string to list and then back again with join

Tags: python, string, join, split, line-breaks

I'm facing difficulties when converting the below string to a list and back again. I want it to preserve the line endings, which uses pythons triple parenthesis (`"""`) to encapsulate a Shakespearean verse. The verse is:

```
fullText= """Hamlet's Soliloquay - Act III Scene i

To QUIZ or not to Be, that is the QUIZ:
Whether tis nobler in the QUIZ to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous QUIZ,
Or to take Arms against a QUIZ of troubles,
And by opposing end them: to die, to QUIZ"""
```

When using `print fullText` the result is as expected. But when I convert this to a list with `fullText.split()` and back again with `" ".join(fullText)` the result is a string with all words on one line.

I know this is normal behaviour, but I can't figure out if there is any way to preserve the line endings.

Obviously I am building a shakespeare quiz asking the user to replace all instances of QUIZ with the correct word!

Comment: BTW, there's no 'a' in "soliloquy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)** instead of **[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)** and join on newlines (as @PM 2Ring suggested) with `"\n".join()`:

```
>>> print "\n".join(fullText.splitlines())
Hamlet's Soliloquay - Act III Scene i

To QUIZ or not to Be, that is the QUIZ:
Whether tis nobler in the QUIZ to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous QUIZ,
Or to take Arms against a QUIZ of troubles,
And by opposing end them: to die, to QUIZ
```

You can achieve the same exact thing with `split` if you split on `\n`:

```
>>> print "\n".join(fullText.split('\n'))
Hamlet's Soliloquay - Act III Scene i

To QUIZ or not to Be, that is the QUIZ:
Whether tis nobler in the QUIZ to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous QUIZ,
Or to take Arms against a QUIZ of troubles,
And by opposing end them: to die, to QUIZ
```

Comment: I'd missed that the OP was using `split` instead of `splitlines`. :oops:

Comment: Great! Wasn't aware splitlines. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `fullText.split()`.
That's causing you to miss your ending of lines (and you won't know where they are).

I'd split into a list of lines, and THEN split each line in each word.